# AS400 Server Java 6 Compatibility

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

I was wondering if anyone knew if the AS400 is compatible with Java 6? I have looked online, and I can only find dated material up to Java 2.

Comment: Whoever voted to close as "too localized", is that a comment on the admittedly shrinking user-base of AS400? Cause I can tell you, it's far from dead and Java on AS400 is certainly still relevant.

Comment: For what it is worth, AS/400 is indeed old.  The current operating system is called IBM i and it runs on POWER 7 hardware.  Searching for AS/400 will probably get very old results.

Comment: Well, IBM still often refer to it as "OS/400", even when talking about version 7.1 or V7R1 as they sometime call it, even though that version scheme is also obsolete as of IBM i. So even though you are correct that AS/400 is not the current name, IBM documentation still frequently refer to "System p" as both "System i", "iSeries" and the good old "AS/400". Similarly, "IBM i" is often referred to as both "i5/OS" and "OS/400". My point is that IBM docs are far from updated or consistent on the matter so often "AS400" yields more correct search results than "Series p" or "IBM i".

Comment: Pap, AS/400 was hardware.  OS/400 was the operating system.  IBM replaced the hardware.  The software ran on the new hardware.  This is the virtue of TIMI architecture, the Technology Independent Machine Interface, you can change hardware and still run the same system software.  Problem is that "AS/400" is very dated.  It is not perceived as relevant in today's market, because it refers to an antique.  It's about like asking if Java 6 is compatible with a PC/XT.  For people to see the platform as relevant, let them know we run on the same hardware as Watson.  Relevant, powerful, modern.

Comment: @WarrenT Yes, I know. What I was saying was that since the IBM documentation is often inconsistent and/or outdated, they often refer to these things by their older names so searching for "As/400" will not necessarily mean you get old results just as searching for "IBM i" (OS) or "System p" (HW) doesn't guarantee correct results. I blame it on the IBM marketing behemoth that seems to run every aspect of that operation these days, renaming and "re-branding" everything once a year.

Comment: @pap I feel the same pain. To their credit IBM does seem to be improving on this score, with some way to go.  They have also committed to the "IBM i" on POWER name for years to come. However at the same time they introduce pureFlex.

Comment: @BuckCalabro the as400 tag maps automatically to ibm-midrange.  Renaming done by marketing does not imply that the platform is outdated.

Comment: @Thorbjørn I agree with you 100%.  I didn't want to start a name war, I just wanted to point out that the current IBM documentation regarding Java 6 will not be found by searching on 'AS/400'.  Using the current name will help OP find current documentation now and in the future.  Yes, there is still some good advice to be found with a search on 'AS/400' but not current, official IBM documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is from version V5R4 option 10.

See

http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas13e0b7af2cf7fa663862577a500503434

Comment: Option 10 is the old JVM.  If you have a choice, get an "IBM Technology for Java" JVM.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just got word that the servers I will be working with are running V6R1M1, and I will recommend using the IBM Technology for Java. =)

Comment: We just found that option 10 is not supported anymore under V7R1

Answer (score 6):

The IBM Java 6 32 bit JDK is available for V5R4 as LPP 5722JV1 Option 11.

For V6R1 and V7R1 the LPP is 5761JV1.  Option 11 is the 32 bit JDK and option 12 is the 64 bit JDK.

You can check installation status of the LPP with the `GO LICPGM` menu and taking option 10.  Press <kbd>F11</kbd> twice to see the option column.

Here is a document for [Installing JDK 6.0 32-Bit (1.6) on R540 of IBM i5/OS](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas102adb33da4e936d0862574a30076f322).

To use Java 6 you simply set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point to the JDK installation path.

For example:

```
ADDENVVAR ENVVAR(JAVA_HOME) VALUE('/QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk60/32bit')
```

or from QSH:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk60/32bit"
```

---

The IBM Technology for Java (J9) is substantially identical to the AIX version and the support group recommended the documentation available at [IBM SDK and Runtime Environment Java Technology Edition Version 6](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v6r0/index.jsp).

The following software technical document may come in handy while working with the midrange JVM:

[IBM Technology for Java (J9) Serviceability - JVMINFO and How to Gather System, Java, Heap, and GcCycle Dumps in IBM i 5.4 and Later](http://www-912.ibm.com/8625680A007CA5C6/1AC66549A21402188625680B0002037E/94C28EBF811A93F78625735C006E2C3C)

The [IBM Support Assistant](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/isa/download.html) workbench has plugin tools for working with and analyzing the various dumps.

Answer (score 2):

The AS400 is compatible with Java 6 *but* you need to explicitly ask for it (as the default is typically an older version).

This used to be done with the "java.version" system property, but that mechanism is being replaced with the "export JAVA_HOME=/...." mechanism for the J9 JVM (the non-Classic one).

Note that *Classic* Java 6 does not (to my experience) include the apt processor, so if you have metainformation (`@Something`) needing to be acted upon (e.g. by Guice) you will need the J9 JVM.